# XSLT transform to .csv with re-usable generated ids

Tags: xslt

New to XSLT and I've been experimenting but want to know if this would be possible.

I want to transform some XML to .csv

The crux of the problem is that I want to create a numeric id for each selected element and then re-use that id for said element to link back

Given the following XML:

```
<root>
  <executables>
    <executable name="foo">
      <executables>
        <executable name="bar"></executable>
      </executables>
    </executable>
  </executables>
  <constraints>
    <constraint name="baz" from="foo" to="bar"></constraint>
  </constraints>
</root>
```

I'd like the result to be something along the lines of:

```
id,type,name,from,to
1,executable,foo,,
2,executable,bar,,
3,constraint,baz,1,2
```

Is this even possible?

Here is my starting XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()" />                     

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>id,type,name,from,to&#xd;&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="executables">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="constraints">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="executable">
        <xsl:number format="1" level="any"/>,executable,<xsl:value-of select="@name" /><xsl:text>,,&#xd;&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="constraint">
        <xsl:number format="1" level="any"/>,constraint,<xsl:value-of select="@name" />,<xsl:value-of select="@from" />,<xsl:value-of select="@to" /><xsl:text>&#xd;&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which gives this result:

```
id,type,name,from,to
1,executable,foo,,
2,executable,bar,,
1,constraint,baz,foo,baz
```

So I basically need to use the `<xsl:number>` matched by the attribute @name, which will be unique. Also the number isn't quite right; it counted from 1 again for the constraint match.

Comment: `<constraint name="baz", from="foo", to="baz">` You cannot have  commas in a tag. Also `baz` does not match `bar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the two `<xsl:number format="1" level="any"/>` I think you want `<xsl:number count="executable | constraint" format="1" level="any"/>`.

For the references set up a key `<xsl:key name="ref" match="executable" use="@name"/>` and then instead of the `<xsl:value-of select="@from" />` use e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="key('ref', @from)" mode="number"/>` and set up

```
<xsl:template match="executable" mode="number">
  <xsl:number level="any"/>
</xsl:template>
```

If the `constraint` elements can also be referenced then use `match="executable | constraint"` in the key declaration and also `<xsl:number count="executable | constraint" level="any"/>` in that template.

And for the `<xsl:value-of select="@to" />` you use `<xsl:apply-templates select="key('ref', @to)" mode="number"/>`.

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQgk

Comment: Is it possible to offset the number by 1? I can't seem to find a way to do that. I need to because the csv will have an artificial row after the header

Comment: In XSLT 3 (perhaps 2 too, I don't rember currently) it is possible to use `start-at` e.g. `<xsl:number level="any" start-at="2"/>`, as done in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQgk/2, but you need an XSLT 3 processor like Saxon 9.8 or later for that. For earlier versions you can of course e.g. `<xsl:variable name="n"><xsl:number count="executable | constraint" format="1" level="any"/></xsl:variable>` and then output `<xsl:value-of select="$n + 1"/>`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use actual generated ids, as mentioned in your title, instead of trying to produce sequential numbering:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="exe-by-name" match="executable" use="@name" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:text>id,type,name,from,to&#xd;&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="executable">
    <xsl:value-of select="generate-id()" />
    <xsl:text>,executable,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
    <xsl:text>,,&#xd;&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="constraint">
    <xsl:value-of select="generate-id()" />
    <xsl:text>,constraint,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(key('exe-by-name', @from))" />
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(key('exe-by-name', @to))" />
    <xsl:text>&#xd;&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Demo (using corrected XML): https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQgk/1

Comment: Thanks, this answer works as well but I do need just an arbritary number, as that is what the consumer of this .csv will expect